# Is there a way to create Hadoop projects on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, intellij-idea

Most of the tutorials involve downloading a VM to use Hadoop.
Is there a way to create Hadoop projects from scratch, or import existing projects using IntelliJ?

Also, I'm working on Windows 10, and adding the environment variables `HADOOP_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` don't seem to be working.

Here's the error I've been getting:

> ```
> Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
>    Please update C:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.2\conf\hadoop-env.cmd
> ```

However, my `JAVA_HOME` *is* set properly.

Comment: Can you tell us how you set `HADOOP_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`?

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of Hadoop is that you have a cluster of nodes that your MapReduce tasks are running on. MapReduce jobs are simply Java programs that you can create in any IDE such as IntelliJ. This code then can be run on your cluster. If you do not have a cluster then you would need to create one which is when you would download a VM.

However, if you only are running it on your computer then there is no point to you using MapReduce since you're cluster would be virtual so you'd be gaining no performance improvement. It sounds like you have a misunderstanding of what Hadoop is. Research it more to understand why what you are trying to do doesn't work.